# usb device name

Tags: usb-drive, 8.04, eeepc

I would like to know if the usb device name is randomly allotted at every reboot in an eeepc netbook with Ubuntu(hardy heron).

What bugs me is that while I transmit some serial data over say ttyUSB0, suddenly the device loses its name and my "dmesg" shows the name to be altered to say ttyUSB1.

I s this a bug in ubuntu? Or can it be manually "fixed"- as in a particular usb port can be mapped to a  particular name.

Any help?

Comment: Hardy Heron is a very old ubuntu distribution, 8.04 that means April 2008. So very few people can have an installation to test your problem. Btw, why are you using hardy?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using the Desktop version of Hardy, the product your using has reached its End of Life already. Please reference [Release Table](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) here. It reached EOL on May 12'th of this year.

Regarding the USB device naming, thats odd that it would randomly stop communicating and reassign the device name. `lsusb` is another command line utility you can use to grab the device information. Did the hardware address change?

If this is occurring often, I would say that its one of three things,The device was disturbed during operation, and the system had that Address locked into the phantom USB device, so it assigned it a new slot. Possible hardware failure (not likely), you have a wonky kernel module thats acting up. My suggestion, upgrade to a maintained version of Ubuntu, and give it a go. I have a eeepc that has no such USB issues.